# interpretation of Walsh spectrum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, harmonic-analysis

Given that the Walsh transform performs operations with the boolean function and a Walsh matrix, how can the Walsh spectrum be interpreted? Specifically, if I were to use the Walsh function for searching non-random sequences, how would I be able to determine that the sequence is non-random given the Walsh spectrum? Is there an analogous result such as what the Fourier transform does to decompose signals that can be visibly seen in the Fourier spectrum?

[image]

Let us say you are given this dot product, how would I be able to interpret the result?
Only answer the last question.